# Make an image from entire ESXi host

Tags: vmware-esxi, disk-image

For some reasons, I need to make an image from entire ESXi host.

It is a physical server, I don't know the root password. It's ESXi 6.0 standalone host.

I want to make a copy from entire server, then make changes on the copy as a VM loaded in the vmware workstation.

Is there any bootable tool?
It's possible to make a VMDK from the host?

PS: I found this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/370898/taking-an-image-backup-of-an-entire-server), but it's very old, maybe there is some new ways...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to move the virtual machines(s) from the ESXi host to VMware Workstation?

Comment: @joeqwerty : Yes, It maybe seems unusual, but I want to move them without changing anything in the host. So, I decided to make a copy from entire ESXi host.